# Change recursion to something less expensive

Tags: c++, graph-theory, dijkstra

im trying to find the shortest path from the vertex to another. To be more precise I have a directed graph and by going always "forward" in it i will always end up in the end. Something like structure of neural network. I decided to find the shortest way with recursion which worked perfectly fine with smaller numbers. But for bigger data I get the SIGSEGV. I almost sure it's the stack overflow. Do any of you have any idea how I can switch from simple recurrence to something that wont cause the trouble?

```
int findShortestPath(Vertex * v, int endPointX){
    if(v->isShortestPathSet())
        return v->getShortestPath();
    vector<int> * paths = new vector<int>;
    if(v->getEndPos() == endPointX)
        return 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v->getOutputEdges().size(); i ++){
        Edge * outputEdge = v->getOutputEdges().at(i);
        paths->push_back(findShortestPath(outputEdge->getOutputVertex(), endPointX) + outputEdge->getValue());
    }
    int minPath = paths->at(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < paths->size(); i ++){
        if(paths->at(i) < minPath)
            minPath = paths->at(i);
    }
    v->setShortestPath(minPath);
    free(paths);
    return minPath;
}
```

this is the function with which im looking for the shortest path. It momorises the shortest possible path to each vertex so in further queries i wont have to repeat these expensive calculations.

Comment: You could use a `std::stack<std::pair<Vertex*,int>>` and a loop in order to avoid the recursive calls. Replace calls to `findShortestPath()` with `push()` and the places where the function returns in the algo with `pop()`. Also if you use `new` you should call `delete paths;` and not `free(paths);`.You could use a `std::stack<std::pair<Vertex*,int>>` and a loop in order to avoid the recursive calls. Replace calls to `findShortestPath()` with `push()` and the places where the function returns in the algo with `pop()`. Also if you use `new` you should call `delete paths;` and not `free(paths);`.

Comment: `vector<int> * paths = new vector<int>` vector already stores its elements on the heap, so this adds little. And if you really insist, use `std::unique_ptr`. The `.at` indexer adds range checking and throws an exception. It's slower than normal `[i]` indexing

Comment: You're leaking lots of memory. The allocated `paths` is not always deleted, and the `free(paths);` won't call the destructor, so while the memory used by actual vector object is freed, the contents of that vector is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the Dijkstra's algorithm iteratively. Here's a snippet of code which implements Dijkstra's algorithm iteratively

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using IntPair = std::pair<int,int>;
std::priority_queue<IntPair, std::vector<IntPair>, std::greater<IntPair>> pq;
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, int>> g;
std::vector<int> distance, parent;

void dijkstras(int startVertex) {
    // insert the startVertex into the priority queue(pq)
    pq.push(std::make_pair(0, startVertex));

    while (!pq.empty()) {
        // select the vertex with least distance travelled so far from the pq
        // and then, pop the selected vertex from pq
        auto [dist, src] = pq.top(); pq.pop();
        // iterate on all its neighbours and update distance[] and parent[]
        for (auto [v, weight] : g[src]) {
            if (int newDist = dist + weight; newDist < distance[v]) {
                parent[v] = src;
                distance[v] = newDist;
                pq.push(std::make_pair(newDist, v));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here,

- `pq` is a priority queue which stores pairs of `(distanceTravelledSoFar, previousNode)`. Here, `pq` acts as a min heap which helps us to choose the next node optimally
- `g` is just an adjacency list that you use to stores the graph
- `distance` is array of the shortest path distances to each of the vertex from `startVertex`
- `parent` is the array which stores the previous node in the shortest path to each vertex from `startVertex`

Here's the [link](https://codeforces.com/contest/20/submission/82725834) to the code which I have used to solve this [question](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/20/C)

Comment: You could just change the `pq` signature to use `std::greater`, to you don't have to use the negative distance... Then you could also switch to using structured bindings, which would clean up the code: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wsb4EM)

Comment: I implemented Dijkstra iteratively in this way and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your question is suggested in the comments (and Cherubim gives a good example of [Dijkstra's algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

I will also answer by modifying you code. Firstly, I think getters and setters are not necessary and you should use modern C++. Therefore I've modified your code as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>

class Vertex;

struct Edge {
    Vertex* const outputVertex;
    int const value;
};

struct Vertex {
    int const endPoint;
    std::vector<Edge const*> const outputEdges;
    std::optional<int> shortestPath;
};

int findShortestPath(Vertex* const v, int endPoint){
    if(v->endPoint == endPoint) return 0;
    if(v->shortestPath.has_value()) return v->shortestPath.value();
    auto const& outputEdges = v->outputEdges; // hopefully prevent one layer of indirection
    std::vector<int> paths; paths.reserve(outputEdges.size());
    std::transform(cbegin(outputEdges), cend(outputEdges), back_inserter(paths),
       [endPoint] (Edge const* const outputEdge) { 
           return findShortestPath(outputEdge->outputVertex, endPoint) + outputEdge->value;
            });
    return v->shortestPath.value() = *std::min_element(cbegin(paths), cend(paths));
}
```

Now, to implement the stack, you have to reverse the concept you are using: instead of recursively going to the depth and returning the distance, you pass the distance forward. Together with the stack suggested in the comments, this would lead to the following code:

```
#include <stack>
#include <utility>
#include <climits>

int findShortestPath(Vertex const* const startVertexPtr, int endPoint) {
    int minDistance = INT_MAX;
    std::stack<std::pair<Vertex const*, int>> s;
    s.push(std::make_pair(startVertexPtr, 0));
    while(!s.empty()) {
        auto [vertexPtr, distance] = s.top(); s.pop(); // structured binding
        if (vertexPtr->endPoint == endPoint) {
            minDistance = std::min(minDistance, distance); // end is found, see if it's path has minimum distance
            continue;
        }
        for(Edge const* const edge : vertexPtr->outputEdges) {
            s.push(std::make_pair(edge->outputVertex, distance + edge->value)); // pass the distance forward
        }
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```

... but you see I'm not using `Vertex::shortestPath` here, which would offer an optimization. I havent' fully checked it, but you can probably do something like this:
First I again redefine `Vertex`

```
struct Vertex {
    int const endPoint;
    std::vector<Edge const*> const outputEdges;
    int shortestPath = INT_MAX;
};
```

And then:

```
int findShortestPath(Vertex const* const startVertexPtr, int endPoint) {
    int minDistance = INT_MAX;
    std::stack<std::pair<Vertex const*, int>> s;
    s.push(std::make_pair(startVertexPtr, 0));
    while(!s.empty()) {
        auto [vertexPtr, distance] = s.top(); s.pop();
        if (vertexPtr->endPoint == endPoint) {
            minDistance = std::min(minDistance, distance);
            continue;
        }
        for(Edge const* const edge : vertexPtr->outputEdges) {
            Vertex& vertex = *edge->outputVertex; // hopefully one less level of indirection
            auto newDistance = distance + edge->value;
            if (newDistance < vertex.shortestPath) {
                vertex.shortestPath = newDistance;
                s.push(std::make_pair(&vertex, newDistance));
            }
        }
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```

But there's probably more optimizations possible.